# How to detect back button pressed from a particular angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to disable logout button from navbar when user lands on login page, I am storing user information in `localstorage`. It works fine for all the pages but when user comes back on login page by back button user's information is still there in localstorage. How to manage this? Please help.

Comment: for the given scenario you can take this strategy. when the user is logged In, and the user tries to go to the login page he will redirect to home page, he can only go to login page after log out and On logout you have to clear `localstorage`

Answer (score 1):

to prevent the user to come back in the login page, you can use guards: CanActivate

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, Router} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CanActivateAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('user') !== null && localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      console.log('logged in user tries to re-login');
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

in your routing module it would be like this

```
  { path: 'loginpage',
    loadChildren: () => import('./features/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
    canActivate: [CanActivateAuthGuard]
  },
```